# Plot a boxplot from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ProteinName': {622: '>sp|O75882|ATRN_HUMAN Attractin OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATRN PE=1 SV=2', 1146: '>sp|O75882|ATRN_HUMAN Attractin OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATRN PE=1 SV=2', 1232: '>sp|O75882|ATRN_HUMAN Attractin OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATRN PE=1 SV=2', 1270: '>sp|O75882|ATRN_HUMAN Attractin OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=ATRN PE=1 SV=2'}, 'Position': {622: 731.0, 1146: 731.0, 1232: 731.0, 1270: 731.0}, 'Glycopeptide': {622: 'R.NSEGQISIFR.Y.HexNAc(4)Hex(5)NeuAc(1)', 1146: 'R.NSEGQISIFR.Y.HexNAc(4)Hex(5)Fuc(1)NeuAc(1)', 1232: 'R.NSEGQISIFR.Y.HexNAc(4)Hex(5)NeuAc(1)', 1270: 'R.NSEGQISIFR.Y.HexNAc(4)Hex(5)Fuc(1)NeuAc(2)'}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-C1': {622: 0.0, 1146: 0.0, 1232: 0.0, 1270: 0.0}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-C2': {622: 32.93651891157215, 1146: 0.0, 1232: 0.0, 1270: 0.0}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-C3': {622: 0.0, 1146: 0.0, 1232: 0.0, 1270: 0.0}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-C4': {622: 34.30630765208948, 1146: 0.0, 1232: 0.0, 1270: 0.0}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-C5': {622: 96.26885645836441, 1146: 0.0, 1232: 0.0, 1270: 0.0}, 'group': {622: 'CONTROL', 1146: 'TREATMENT', 1232: 'TREATMENT', 1270: 'TREATMENT'}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-T1': {622: 0.0, 1146: 50.31435590892384, 1232: 0.0, 1270: 0.0}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-T2': {622: 0.0, 1146: 0.0, 1232: 56.079171598895186, 1270: 43.920828401104814}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-T3': {622: 0.0, 1146: 31.116328385337777, 1232: 68.88367161466222, 1270: 0.0}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-T4': {622: 0.0, 1146: 20.64630643302238, 1232: 35.10173373882788, 1270: 27.416074077070935}, 'icPercentageGly_PCU-T5': {622: 0.0, 1146: 24.95894470029631, 1232: 44.43968440969619, 1270: 30.601370890007495}})
```

I want to create a boxplot that will have a box for each value in the "Glycopeptide" column, the values will be the content of the columns that start with "icPercentage" and the color of the boxes will be given by the "Group" column.

I've tried to melt and make an initial plot with:

```
plotdf = pd.melt(v, id_vars = ['Position','group', 'Glycopeptide','ProteinName'])
plotdf.boxplot(column=['Glycopeptide'], by=['group'])
```

But I get this error:

```
ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Using seaborn perhaps: `sns.boxplot(x='Glycopeptide', y='value', hue='group', data=plotdf)`.

Comment: what's `plots.dtypes`?

Comment: I managed to make it work by using this: `plotdf.boxplot(column=['value'], by = ['Glycopeptide'])` . Is there a way to color by group?

Comment: @BigBen tried with seaborn as you suggested and worked perfectly, thank you